# breaking blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My son cannot break blocks anywhere, in any mode. ALso he cannot attack anything. He tried using the Wiki; but no success. He tried breaking dirt with a shovel, he tried breaking stone with a pickax, he tried to attack slimes with a sword, nothing works. help!

Comment: When did this start happening? Is the arm swing animation occurring? Is this affecting all worlds, or just one?

Comment: This question has been asked many times on this site. I would advise you to check out the other questions since this one will probably be deleted

Comment: I cannot swing my arm. ALl worlds affected.

Comment: Also I don't think this is a duplicate question because he cannot break blocks in ANY mode---survival or creative.

Answer (score 1):

It has likely that your son has changed his controls accidentally, or changed them and forgot about it.

In <kbd>Options</kbd> ⇒ <kbd>Controls</kbd>, make sure that `Attack/Destroy` is set to <kbd>Button 1</kbd>. If it is not, you can press <kbd>Reset</kbd> to set it back:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about minecraft, it may be beacuse of /gamemode 2 or spawn protection, if singleplayer, use Survival Mode not Adventure mode. Adventure mode makes you only can break no blocks except from specific on tools!

Comment: He can't break blocks in creative mode either. Nowhere. Could it be a mouse issue?

Comment: Would the mouse be a problem, he wouldn't even be able to start the game/open a world. Maybe its the key/button-bindings(see colorfusions answer)